# Spectral radius of the product of a right stochastic matrix and hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let us define the following matrix multiplication:

$C=AB$

where $B$ is a block diagonal matrix with $N$ blocks, $B_1$, $B_2$ … $B_N$, each of dimensions $M \times M$. I know that $B_k = I_M - \mu R_k$ with $R_k$ equals to a hermitian matrix and $\mu$ some positive constant. Moreover, I know that the the entries of the matrix $A$ are non-negative real numbers. I also know that the matrix $A$ is right stochastic, i.e., the sum of the elements in each row equals one. In particular, the matrix $A$ has the following structure

$A=P \cdot blkdiag\{A_g \otimes I_{M-1},I_N\} \cdot P^T$

where $P$ is a permutation matrix, $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product, $I_{M-1}$ is an $(M-1 \times M-1)$ identity matrix, $I_N$ equals an $(N\times N)$ identity matrix, $A_g$ denotes a $(N\times N)$ right stochastic matrix with non-negative real entries and $blkdiag\{.\}$ equals a block diagonal matrix.

Can I say that the spectral radius of C is smaller than one for some values of $\mu$? If so, can I determine the range of values of $\mu$ under which the spectral radius of $C$ is smaller than one?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $C$ is a block diagonal matrix with $N$ diagonal blocks of size $M$. It seems very unlikely that a single parameter $\mu$ will be able to exercise the desired control in the an extreme case, such as $R_k = 2^k R_1$. Regardless, please confirm the block diagonal structure of  $C$ as this seems significant. Kind regards

Comment: $C$ does not have a block diagonal structure. To avoid confusions, I have re-defined the structure of $A$ by adding some permutations matrices